# Can't get a Source Editor extension working in Xcode 10

Tags: swift, xcode, macos-mojave, xcode-extension

Using Xcode 10 running in Mojave I can't get a simple test source editor extension working. I use to be able to do it under Xcode 9 High Sierra. I created a bare bones source editor extension. I then run it but doesn't show up under the debut Xcode (black icon) Editor menu. Also doesn't show up in System>Extension list. Rebooting didn't help either. I tried downloading LineX extension from the Mac App Store but it wouldn't work either.

Comment: I have the same problem in Xcode 10 / High Sierra and couldn't find a solution yet. I get errors *Failed to read clone map from disk: The file “device_map.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file* and  *Failed to find extension point com.apple.dt.Xcode.extension.source-editor in the binding map*

Comment: Got the same error but there is more: `IDEExtensionManager: Xcode Extension does not meet code signing requirement: com.example.XCExt.XCExtTestExtension (file:///Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XCExt-eipfmhdvyelzuogibudxobsakeef/Build/Products/Debug/XCExt.app/Contents/PlugIns/XCExtExtension.appex/), Error Domain=DVTSecErrorDomain Code=-67050 "code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)}`. Looks like an issue with automatic codesigning but I haven't had time to further investigate.

Comment: Xcode 10.1 seems to fix the issue.

Comment: What did you do to try and create a new project with an Xcode Editor extension?  It's no longer an option in Xcode 10.1.

Comment: I'd try manually creating your own certs, downloading them and assigning them.  It sucks when things magically start working and we have no idea why they started failing or started working.  Yea, Apple! /s

Comment: For anyone else having the same issue as @vadian, try re-registering Xcode with Launch services: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -f /path/to/Xcode.app`.

Answer (score 5):

Renaming or moving the Xcode will fix the issue. Since High Sierra since `/usr/libexec/xpccachectl` (the preferred solution) does not seem to exist in this version of the OS.

#### To fix quickly:

- Quit Xcode
- Rename Xcode in the applications folder temporarily.
- Launch renamed Xcode
- Quit Xcode
- Name it back to old value

Answer (score 1):

It's now fixed but I have no idea how. After working on it for four days I about gave up. I wanted to retry LineX extension but I first searched my drive for all files containing LineX and deleted them Except for the one in the Applications folder. I restarted the Mac and went to bed. Next morning its was working. LineX and two other extensions plus my extension showed up in System>Extensions and now are working. I hate when something starts working but you don't know why but I guess it's better than not working.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for High Sierra 10.13.6: install "Security Update Developer Beta 10.13.6" (2018-002)" from Mac App Store. I've got "Xcode Source Editor" in the Extensions prefpane back right after post-update reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue when was trying to run Xcode Source Editor extension (Xcode 11.2.1). As a result - my extension didn't appear in "Editor" menu.

**Here's a list of all my actions (after following them the problem has gone):**

Make sure that signing for both host app and extension is set to "Automatic" and Signing Certificate is set to "Development" (or any other except "To Run Locally").

Then:

1. Go to **Xcode settings**, select "**Accounts**" tab, select your **Apple ID** account (add it if you don't have yet)
2. In "**Teams**" table select your team (you should have at least one - **Personal Team**)
3. Click "**Download Manual Profiles**"
4. Click "**Manage Certificates...**", then click a "**+**" button and choose "**Apple Development**"

Xcode might ask you a password for your development keychain (NOT your system one) - **leave password field empty and press Return**.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My Xcode Source Editor extensions have, on more than one occasion, disappeared from Xcode. Each time they have disappeared, I always eventually got them to reappear––until Xcode 12.  With Xcode 12 I was unable get any Source Editor extensions to show up in System Preferences/Extensions, until today.

I just found the answer to why Xcode Source Editor extensions keep disappearing:  It has to do with my maintaining older versions of Xcode on my my MacOS Catalina system.  I keep Xcode versions 10, 11, and 12 on my development system, and according to this thread that I found:  https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat/issues/494

The thread quotes from The article [Xcode​Kit and Xcode Source Editor Extensions by Zoë Smith, March 25th, 2019](https://nshipster.com/xcode-source-extensions/), says:

> Finally, when multiple copies of Xcode are on the same machine, extensions can stop working completely. In this case, Apple Developer Relations suggests re-registering your main copy of Xcode with Launch Services (it’s easiest to temporarily add lsregister’s location to PATH first):

```
% PATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support:"$PATH"
% lsregister -f /Applications/Xcode.app
```

After issuing these terminal commands my Source Editor Extensions are now, once again, available!